# Org-agenda time grid face, a bug?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a problem with org-agenda time grid. Whatever the theme I use, the first number in the time grid has not the correct face, see image. This is the case even with basic configuration. Any idea?

[image: Org-time-grid]

Comment: what is the correct face you need?

Comment: The same as the remaining numbers, namely org-time-grid.

Comment: This is most probably a problem with your init file. Start with `emacs -q`: does it occur? If not, bisect your init file to find the problem. In any case, you should probably add to your question the faces for the initial `1` (I presume from your comment that the face of the subsequent digit is `org-time-grid`). Otherwise there is very little information to go on.